# Div Overlapping with datepicker

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have 2 divs.

First one is a datepicker div and below it i have a graph.when i try to pick a date, datepicker does not work because of overlapping of these 2 divs. I want to suppress datepicker over graph div.

```
//here is image
http://tinypic.com/r/1549hlz/8




<div id="cal" name="cal"  align="center" style="align: center; float: center; padding-    right: 150px;" >
<form    name="form" method="post">
<span >From</span> <input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from"    onclick="setSens('date_to', 'max');" readonly="true">
<span >Till</span> <input type="text" name="date_to" id="date_to"   onclick="setSens('date_from', 'min');" readonly="true"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input name="submit"  onclick="show6(); update6();" type="submit"  id="submit"    value="Akım">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input name="submit"  onclick="show6(); update8();"      type="submit"  id="submit" value="Güç">
 </form>
 </div> 


<div id="graph3"  name="graph3"   align="center" style="display:none;width:1000px;height: 250px;">Akım-Zaman Grafiği</div><br/><br/><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">


 function update6(){
     graph drawing.....
 }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


 function update8(){
    another graph drawing..... (not important for  the case)
 }
 </script>


<script>
 function show6(){
document.getElementById("graph3").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("cal").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, can you post the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

You have not cleared your float.

Put this between both DIV's

```
    <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
```

So ...

```
<div id="cal" name="cal"  align="center" style="align: center; float: center; padding-    right: 150px;" >
<form name="form" method="post">
<span >From</span> <input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from"    onclick="setSens('date_to', 'max');" readonly="true">
<span >Till</span> <input type="text" name="date_to" id="date_to"   onclick="setSens('date_from', 'min');" readonly="true"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input name="submit"  onclick="show6(); update6();" type="submit"  id="submit"    value="Akım">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input name="submit"  onclick="show6(); update8();"      type="submit"  id="submit" value="Güç">
</form>

    <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>  

<div id="graph3"  name="graph3"   align="center" style="display:none;width:1000px;height: 250px;">Akım-Zaman Grafiği</div>

<br/><br/><br/>
```

p.s. No need to state type="text/javascript"  is fine. You only need one set of  tags for all three scripts.

```
'<script>
 function update6(){
     graph drawing.....
 }

 function update8(){
    another graph drawing..... (not important for  the case)
 }

function show6(){
document.getElementById("graph3").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("cal").style.display = 'block';
}

</script>'
```

Comment: i tried z index but nothing changed,i also put the code above

Comment: thanks friend,it worked, the right part "date_to" is ok,but in the left part "date_from" ,i cant change months mean left part still crushing with graph below it.

Comment: Can you give me a link so I can see.

Comment: just find out,right part also crushing,right part's right button is out of graph so it is working because of that which takes me to the beginning :C